# importing range from another book using data validation in google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, import, dropdown

I want a drop-down list here :

[image]

But the range is in another book called : sheet with range

[image]

I've tried to use data validation with "IMPORTRANGE" without success , making the following:

=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A8v4TEgibkesX729YcjEDn8RkcogutT_8pgIkggaBfI/edit#gid=0", "Hoja 1!A1:A5)

I get the following :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qfJw.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible. you need to import your list in some column first (you can hide it in 3 ways) and only then you can create your dropdown

Comment: I really want that data is centralized. Each time I duplicate "sheet from end", I have not to do the same again and again.

Comment: @NIN I can understand your need for this, unfortunately at this point, google sheets does not support such functionality

Comment: maybe google sheet developers  take into account this. . . definitly would be awesome. Well, thank you.